# Haskell - delete function doesn't work

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a bounded queue. The bounded queue consists of two parts, the queue itself (a queue of numbers) and its capacity.

```
type Queue = [Int]
type Capacity = Int
data BoundedQueue = BoundedQueue Queue Capacity deriving (Show)
```

Examples of the BoundedQueue:

```
bq1 :: BoundedQueue
bq1 = BoundedQueue [1,2,3,4,5] 5
bq2 :: BoundedQueue
bq2 = BoundedQueue [] 5
```

I want to create a delete function. The function is to delete a number from a specified bounded queue.

```
delete :: Int -> BoundedQueue -> BoundedQueue
delete int (BoundedQueue [] ys) = error "Not found"
delete int (BoundedQueue (x:xs) ys) | int == x = (BoundedQueue xs ys)
                                    | otherwise = delete int (BoundedQueue xs ys)
```

But the delete function doesn't work properly. It also deletes everything that preceded the deleted item. Here's a example:

```
*Main> delete 2 bq1
BoundedQueue [3,4,5] 5
```

when it should be

```
BoundedQueue [1,3,4,5] 5
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you traverse the queue in `delete` you remove all items until you find the one you want. You'll need to reinsert the elements that you want to keep:

```
delete :: Int -> BoundedQueue -> BoundedQueue
delete int (BoundedQueue [] c) = error "Not found"
delete int (BoundedQueue (x:xs) c) 
  | int == x  = (BoundedQueue xs c)                                  
  | otherwise = 
    let BoundedQueue xs' _ = delete int (BoundedQueue xs c)
    in BoundedQueue (x:xs') c 
 --                  ^-- keep the current element as well
```

Works as intended:

```
λ> delete 2 bq1
BoundedQueue [1,3,4,5] 5
```

---

You might also want to remove the `error` call and make the types say that `delete` is a partial operation:

```
delete :: Int -> BoundedQueue -> Maybe BoundedQueue
delete int (BoundedQueue [] c) = Nothing
delete int (BoundedQueue (x:xs) c)
  | int == x  = Just (BoundedQueue xs c)
  | otherwise = do
    BoundedQueue xs' _ <- delete int (BoundedQueue xs c)
    Just (BoundedQueue (x:xs') c)
```

Comment: Awesome! Welcome to Stack Overflow! (You accept an answer by checking the checkbox to the side of the answer)

Comment: You might also consider returning the empty list instead of an error in the empty list case. After all, delete is supposed to ensure that the given number isn't in the list and that is trivially true for the empty list. In most cases where you would use this function, that would be a little more convenient than the Maybe solution. Maybe is best for when there really isn't an answer. For example, Maybe would be a good return type for the head function because there is really no answer to the head of an empty list.